# Is it possible to set ‚is executable‘ property of .app file in OpenSuse programmatically?

Tags: console, executable, labview, opensuse

I‘m working with Labview executables. Unfortunatly, in some cases, Labview or OpenSuse looses the check mark on the ‚is executable‘ property of that .app file. Is it possible to set that file-property with some lines of codes?
Thank you all and regards,
Urs

Answer (score 0):

The [standard Unix/Linux shell command](https://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4124/) to make a file executable is

`chmod +x filename`

You don't say what kind of 'code' you want to use but you can type that at the command line (where `filename` is the file you want to change), or in most languages there should be a syntax for executing a system command.

For example in LabVIEW itself you can use [System Exec](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/glang/system_exec/) - or you could just use the [Set Permissions](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/glang/set_permissions/) function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. In the Labview Forum, someone helped me to solve the problem, exactly the way you described it :)

[chmod command in labview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv46D.png)

Thank you!!!